# How do I assign values from a dictionary to a dataframe column in equal numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, assignment-operator

I have a list of sales reps for one of 5 territories. I need to assign them to a list of leads in equal numbers.

Here's an example of the dictionary:

```
d = {'Large': 'Jackson', 'Large': 'Stevens', 'Large': 'Miller', 'Medium': 'James', 'Medium': 'Samuels', 'Medium': 'Shandler', 'Small': 'Fast', 'Small': 'Shorter'}
```

Here's an example of the leads list dataframe as I want it to look after assigning the sales rep from the dictionary to the Sales Rep column:

| Client Size | Sales Rep |
| --- | --- |
| Large | Jackson |
| Large | Stevens |
| Medium | James |
| Medium | Samuels |
| Medium | Shandler |
| Medium | James |
| Medium | Samuels |
| Medium | Shandler |
| Small | Fast |
| Small | Shorter |
| Small | Fast |
| Small | Shorter |
| Small | Fast |
| Small | Shorter |

Here's the code I've been able to come up with thus far:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a dictionary
d = {'Large': 'Jackson', 'Large': 'Stevens', 'Large': 'Miller', 'Medium': 'James', 'Medium': 'Samuels', 'Medium': 'Shandler', 'Small': 'Fast', 'Small': 'Shorter'}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('clientlist.csv')

# Assign the dictionary values to the DataFrame column
df['Sales Rep'] = df['Client Size'].map(d)
```

I can't figure out how to write a function that will somehow count the number of matching values in the Client Size column of the dataframe and then evenly distribute the values from the dictionary.

Comment: I am very confused by your description (might just be my English...), but why is "Large": "Miller" missing, and why is everything duplicated twice? Do you mind clarifying

Comment: It seems like you need to convert your dict to a list of dicts which each have the same two keys.

Comment: p.s. don't use `dict` as a variable name since the python builtin library already has a class named `dict`.

Comment: Your dictionary is not what you think it is... `{'Large': 'Miller', 'Medium': 'Shandler', 'Small': 'Shorter'}`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting the dict to a list of dicts. I will use the name `d` instead of `dict` to avoid a name clash with the built-in class `dict`:

```
sales = [{'Client Size': k, 'Sales Rep': v for k, v in d.items()]
```

Now you can get a dataframe from this list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```